# Porque no funciona el componente Script de next?

Tags: script, nextjs

Tengo mi `_document` que retorna esto:

```
  <Html lang="en-US">
    <Head>
      <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;600;700;900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet"
      />
    </Head>
    <body>
      <div id="nprogress-container" />
      <Main />
      <NextScript />
    </body>
  </Html>
```

En el `Head` tengo

```
 <NextHead>
  <title>{title}</title>
  ...
  {children}
</NextHead>
```

Intento usar este componente, probe colocandolo dentro de `NextHead`, dentro de `Head` o dentro de `Html`, pero cuando se renderiza la pagina no encuentro el elemento con id `keymetric`

```
    <Script
      id="keymetric"
      src="https://km12541.keymetric.net/KeyMetric.js"
      type="text/javascript"
    />
```

Si en cambio utilizo el `<script>` tradicional (dentro de `NextHead`) el script ahora aparece. Pero recibo un warning en consola indicandome que deberia usar el componente `Next/Script`.

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Estaba colocando mal el componente `Script`, si lo coloco dentro de `_app` al final del context provider (pero dentro de él) funciona correctamente:

```
<GlobalProvider>
  <Component {...pageProps} />
  <Script
    src="https://km12541.keymetric.net/KeyMetric.js"
    type="text/javascript"
  />
</GlobalProvider>
```